# Erro ao criar virtual host no Apache 2

Tags: php, virtualhost, host, apache

Quanto tento criar uma virtual host no apache não consigo acessa-la

Já segui os seguintes procedimento:

Ir até o `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

e colocar o `127.1.0.1 meusite.dev`

Ir até o `C:\Apache\conf\httpd.conf`

e Descomentar a linha: `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Ir até o `C:\Apache\conf\extra\vhost.conf`

e colocar:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/htdocs/teste
   ServerName  meusite.dev
   ServerAlias meusite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

mesmo assim não funcionou.

***Obs: Não estou usando o Xampp nenhum o Wamp, estou fazendo só com o Apache 2.4***